# Surefire 2.22.0 is not running unit test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

My project is in Java 11. I am using Junit 4 in my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and jacoco-maven-plugin version 0.8.3

Now I tried to upgrade from maven-surefire-plugin version 2.21.0 to 2.22.0, which stopped running most of the test cases without giving any build issue and hence the coverage came down.

All of the test classes are following the correct naming convention *Test.java

Please suggest if anybody has faced similar issue.